# Custom ContractResolver not working while serializing JSON using JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a custom ContractResolver which serializes selective properties. On each client request, I'm creating an instance of it passing a boolean value (depending on the condition) and setting it as the ContractResolver for the JsonFormatter.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(false);
```

While debugging, the `protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)` method is never hit.

I can't figure out why the new ContractResolver isn't getting set in the JsonFormatter.

Also, the method where I'm setting the new ContractResolver looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public CustObj GetInfo(string param)
```

I can't really do something like `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, formatter);` as I need to return `CustObj`.

NOTE: I'm setting the JsonFormatter in `Global.asax.cs` file.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the application was using a custom `ContentNegotiator` due to which resetting the json formatter wasn't working. The `ContentNegotiator` was set as below in Global.asax file.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(jsonFormatter));
```

So, for each request in the controller, I call this method which basically replaces the existing `ContentNegotiator`.

```
    private void SetNewJsonFormatterWithCustomContractResolver(bool returnMVFormat)
    {
        //Create a new JsonMediaTypeFormatter
        var newJsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        newJsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(returnMVFormat)
        };

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IContentNegotiator), new JsonContentNegotiator(newJsonFormatter));
    }
```